# Server s-de or client side detection on how many browsers are installed on customer machine

Tags: java, javascript, servlets, http-headers

Is there any way to detect which browsers are installed on customer's machine after customers clicks on a URL. Usecase is below :

We are hosting a redirect server and URL for this redirect server would be provided to customers. On click of this URL , as customer lands on the redirect server servlet, we will fetch his user agent and detect from which browser he is coming. But if the browser he is using is an unsupported version for our application ,   I want to detect if he has any other supported browser versions installed on his machine and open that URL in that browser.

I am aware that this is something we can not do server side but is this something we can do on client side may be by using JS or something ?

Let me know. Thanks!

Comment: If you understand you can't do it server-side, then why are you tag spamming? And this sort of "your browser is unsupported" is *very* bad practice. Unless you're just talking about detecting and warning about ancient versions of browsers, it causes more problems than it ever solves.

Comment: Yes, our usecase does involve warning users about the old browser versions and redirect them to new "supported" browsers automatically and hence the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is not going to be possible in the general case; JavaScript APIs are sandboxed to prevent malicious scripts from stealing confidential information from clients. You could theoretically make this work with some sort of client-side plugin, such as a Java applet, but such an approach would be very platform-dependent and almost certainly not worth the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You can only detect the browser being *used*, not the browsers *installed*. Detecting the browsers *installed* would require the ability to snoop on the user's machine and look through their files.  What browser do you think is going to implement such functionality to allow you to do that?  None, unless they want to get sued into oblivion.